# ModernHttpClient for .Net Standard 2.0 in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, httpclient

I am trying to install ModernHttpClient from ManagedNUGet. But after installation completed, it says following warning. I am trying to install in Portable project.

> Package 'modernhttpclient 2.4.2' was restored using '.NetFramework,
>   version=4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NetStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you're using .NET Standard you don't have to use ModernHttpClient. Just go to properties of your project and select HttpClientHandler implementation.

Android:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=macos

iOS: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack

Comment: Note that the `AndroidClientHandler` requires Android >= 5.0, so if you're supporting versions below that you're probably still stuck with ModernHttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a portable class library for your shared project. For a long time that was (and partially still is) the standard type of a shared code library for xamarin (forms).

However, since Microsoft introduced the .Net Standard, developers are encouraged to create .net standard class libraries instead of using the old PCL approach.
So a lot of nuget packages get updates which make them compatible with .net standard, however the support for portable class libraries gets dropped.

Basically you have to convert your pcl to a .net standard class library if you want to use that particular nuget package.

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for reply. I usually install packages from NUGet. So, I just go into Manage NUGet for sharable library(Portable Class Library) of my project and tried to install in it. Is there any other way to install `ModernHttpClient`? And How can I convert that PCL library `ModernHttpClient` into .NetStandard supported?

Comment: Check this link:
https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/

After you have converted your PCL, you should be able to install the nuget package.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am working on new project which is .NetStandard(not converting PCL to .NetStandard). Which NUGet I should use for `ModernHttpClient` in .NetStandard 2.0? Please explain me if I uderstand wrongly. I am new for .NetStandard 2.0